# sscanf optional column

Tags: c, gcc

I wish to use sscanf to read a file with data which has the following format with one important criterion "furtherdata" is optional.

aidsomedatafurtherdata

```
sscanf(currentline[i], "%[^\t] %[^\t] %11 [^\n]", aIDVar, someDataVar, furtherDatVar) ==  3
```

Is there a way of doing this thanks?

Answer (score 3):

You can generally do this by checking the return value of `*scanf` to ensure the correct number of parameters were scanned, something like the following complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void testFn (char *str) {
    int var1, var2, var3;

    if (sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &var1, &var2, &var3) !=  3) {
        var3 = 42;
        if (sscanf(str, "%d %d", &var1, &var2) !=  2) {
            var1 = var2 = var3 = -1;
        }
    }
    printf ("[%-10s] -> %3d %3d %3d\n", str, var1, var2, var3);
}

int main (void) {
    testFn ("");
    testFn ("1");
    testFn ("1 2");
    testFn ("1 2 3");
    testFn ("1 2 3 4");

    return 0;
}
```

The output shows that you need two parameters with an optional third:

```
[          ] ->  -1  -1  -1
[1         ] ->  -1  -1  -1
[1 2       ] ->   1   2  42
[1 2 3     ] ->   1   2   3
[1 2 3 4   ] ->   1   2   3
```

You'll need to adapt that to your particular data, but that's the basic theory. Try for the larger quantity first and, if that's no good, try for a lower quantity with defaults.

---

Addendum:

As ugoren points out in a comment, the `*scanf` doesn't need to be repeated in this scenario. In fact, that would be problematic for something like `fscanf` where the file pointer would have moved after the first attempt.

Because the directives are processed sequentially, you can just store the return value and reuse it - the first two directives would have already been actioned (stored to `var1` and `var2`) before the failure on the third `%d`. The `testFn` function could be rewritten as:

```
static void testFn (char *str) {
    int quant, var1, var2, var3;

    if ((quant = sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &var1, &var2, &var3)) !=  3)
        if (quant ==  2)
            var3 = 42;
        else
            var1 = var2 = var3 = -1;
    printf ("[%-10s] -> %3d %3d %3d\n", str, var1, var2, var3);
}
```

Comment: Is the second `sscanf` needed? Can't you simply `sscanf` once, then you're OK if you have 3, should set `var3` if you have 2, fail otherwise.

Comment: @ugoren, good point, I'll add that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond absolutely trivial input, `fgets` is usually a better tool than `scanf`. It's not tough to:

```
void input(char *str){
    int x, vars[3];
    char *sp;
    for(x=0,sp=strtok(str, " \t");x<3&&sp; x++,sp=strtok(NULL, " \t")){
          vars[x] = atoi(sp);
    }
    if(x<3) //didn't read enough
       //..deal with it
    if(sp) //your optional field is present
       //deal with that.
}
```